# .htaccess file not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I got my website done by my friend it is up and running in the public server. I tried to run the same website on my internal server. But  apache says file not found. I figured out that the problem is in .htaccess file. This is my file

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and in my apache conf file I set

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /srv/www/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 192.168.43.0/255.255.255.0 192.168.42.0/255.255.255.0
<Directory /srv/www/companies/test1/>
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order Allow,Deny
            Deny from all
            Allow from 192.168.43.0/255.255.255.0 192.168.42.0/255.255.255.0
    </Directory>
    </Virtualhost>
```

error log says

```
[Fri Apr 11 16:57:33 2014] [error] [client 192.168.43.8] File does not exist:/srv/www/cms
[Fri Apr 11 16:57:33 2014] [error] [client 192.168.43.19] File does not exist:/srv/www/products, referer: http://192.168.43.8/companies/
```

I guess htaccess is lokking for index.php in **/srv/www/** folder instead of **/srv/www/companies/test1/** folder. Any suggestion how to direct htaccess in correct location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a cms and product directory in /srv/www/companies/test1/ instead of /src/www/ you could fix the issue by changing your `DocumentRoot /srv/www/` to `DocumentRoot /srv/www/companies/test1/` and restarting apache.

Generally though, you'd want to set up a custom VirtualHost for each site you are planning on serving and leave the default `<VirtualHost *:80>` set to whatever should be served by default when you visit your IP address.

See [VirtualHost Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for some examples of common setups.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But I cant change my DocumentRoot as there are other services running. Maybe can I use other port for this site?

Comment: I suggest you implement what I mentioned in the second part of my answer and setup a new VirtualHost with the DocumentRoot set to the correct path. 

You can either use another port or use the same port but switch to "named virtual hosts" that use the Host: header to determine which site should be served. Examples of each of these scenarios are available from my "VirtualHost Examples" link.

Answer (score 1):

the .htaccess file is located in the root folder of your instalation and by default is hidden.

If you are using FileZilla:

1. Start FileZilla then select the "Server" menu at the top
2. Select "Force showing Hidden Files"